# Does firefox temporarely store history on disk in private mode?

Tags: firefox

In private browsing, does firefox (for PC version) only store history (including cookies etc) in memory, or does it also store them on disk and delete them on exit?

Answer (score 0):

In Private Browsing Mode, no items are written to the History at all. To the best of my knowledge, Recently Closed Tabs are all kept in memory. The same applies to cookies.

That said, if you have a Windows [page file](https://www.howtogeek.com/126430/htg-explains-what-is-the-windows-page-file-and-should-you-disable-it/) (essentially virtual memory stored on hard disk) active on your PC (which most do by default), it is possible to recover data from there, mostly with the help of special forensics tools. Linux distributions use swap files, which fulfill much of the same function (though I don't know how susceptible to forensics they are).